# Is StoreId of an Outlook Store globally unique?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

And if so, can the EntryId and StoreId be used as a globally unique identifier for an Outlook Folder. By globally unique I mean, a StoreId for an Outlook Store once generated for an Outlook instance on a device will not be regenerated anywhere else in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes, they are unique. Exchange store entry id embeds for the mailbox DN (EX address) and the SMTP address of the owner; so you can end up with the same store entryid, but they will be referring to the same mailbox.